# ImageJ: How to adjust color of plotted ellipses based on pre-defined RGB values?

Tags: colors, imagej, data-fitting, imagej-macro, drawellipse

I plot ellipses using a txt file which consists all parameters (x,y coordinates, major/minor axes, angle of the major axis) and RGB values for each ellipse. Plotting ellipses is the easy part, however I cannot define the color of ellipses based on the RGB code. I can simply solve this problem with Gnuplot but for other reasons I have to use ImageJ. Can anyone help me with this?

I use this code:

```
`// import file with coordinates, major and minor axis, angle of rotation (CW degrees)
fileName = File.openDialog("Select the file to import");
allText = File.openAsString(fileName);
text = split(allText, "\n");

for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    line = split(text[i], ",");
    XM = parseFloat(line[1]); // Assuming the X coordinate is in the first column
    YM = parseFloat(line[2]); // Assuming the Y coordinate is in the second column
    Major = parseFloat(line[3]); // Assuming the major axis is in the third column
    Minor = parseFloat(line[4]); // Assuming the minor axis is in the fourth column
    Angle = parseFloat(line[5]); // Assuming the rotation angle is in the fifth column

run("Specify...", "width=" + Major + " height=" + Minor + " x=" + XM + " y=" + YM + " oval       centered");
   run("Rotate...", "angle=" + Angle+90);
   run("Draw");
   roiManager("add");
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

> Plotting ellipses is the easy part, however I cannot define the color
> of ellipses based on the RGB code.

**Color.set(value)**
Sets the drawing color. For 8 bit images, 0<=value<=255. For 16 bit images, 0<=value<=65535. With RGB images, use hex constants (e.g., 0xff0000 for red).

Comment: Yes, I have used this one, but I got only black or dark grey ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

```
R = parseInt(line[9]);
G = parseInt(line[10]);
B = parseInt(line[11]); 

setColor(R, G, B);

run("Specify...", "width=" + Major + " height=" + Minor + " x=" + XM + " 
y=" + YM + " oval centered");
run("Rotate...", "angle=" + Angle);
run("Draw");
run("Fill");
roiManager("add");
}
function setColor(r, g, b) {
setForegroundColor(r, g, b);
run("Select None");
}
```

This was the missing part. It is now working well when RGB image is open.

Comment: I can't see "Color.set();" in your code (and please read carefully about the hex values). Furthermore, are you sure your image is of type RGB?

Comment: "Missing part ?", isn't it a prerequisite ?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Obviously, it was the OP who answered his own question and who has posted his code that in fact is unrelated to the initial problem. The problem was that drawing something onto a gray-level image won't show any colours. The image must of course be defined as RGB-type. In my opinion there is no need to add any explanations to the OP's code because the code is totally irrelevant concerning the initial problem.